# C# overwrite Existing Cookie in CookieContainer?

Tags: c#, cookies

I request a page with `HTTPWebRequest` and using this code. I add cookie

```
agent.cookieJar.Add(new Uri("http://www.website.com"),
    new Cookie("brbr", "harta&brbra&=-"));
```

I ended up with two of the same cookies with different values in each of them. Because the
request has Javascript cookies sent back. What function should I use to
overwrite/update "brbr" cookie When I need to?

Answer (score 2):

Their is overwrite method available in C# HttpCookie clas but you can overwrite the value of the cookie as you want as shown below

```
Request.Cookies["brbr"] = "Some New Value";

Or

Response.Cookies["brbr"] = "Some New Value";
```

Comment: I use cookie container and I get the following error
The name 'Response' does not exist in the current context
The name 'Request' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 0):

Kind of an old question, but figured I would post anyway.  The [Set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookiecollection.set%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method on your cookie collection should do the job.

```
agent.cookieJar.Set(new HttpCookie("brbr", "harta&brbra&=-"));
```

This way you don't have to worry if the cookie already exists or not.